# Updating a git repo blindly, possibly to a different branch

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

As part of deployment automation, I have a local git repository that was created with a command of the form

```
git clone --single-branch -b $BRANCH $REMOTE $PATH
```

From time to time it is necessary for the automation to pull further changes from the remote, and this *may* involve a change of branch.  The automation has no state; it knows what the branch is supposed to be, but not what it was.  Also, there *should* never be any local changes in this repository, but mistakes happen.

I am looking for a command, or sequence of commands, that will have the same overall effect as wiping out the repository and re-cloning it, but which will minimize the amount of data re-downloaded in the common case (i.e. `$BRANCH` has not changed and `git pull` would have done a fast-forward merge).

Answer (score 0):

Getting most of the way there is easy: just confirm a few things and then run `git fetch` etc.  As a sort of proto-type shell script:

```
cd ... # the place you want to test.
       # note that `git-sh-setup` (below) demands
       # that this be the top of the repository.

git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null || exit 1
```

(this verifies that it is in fact a git repository)

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) || exit 1
```

(this tests which branch is currently checked-out, if any; it fails with `fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref` if HEAD is detached; refine with `-q` and a different error if needed)

```
if ! git rev-parse --verify refs/remotes/$remote/$branch >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "$remote/$branch does not exist" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

(this makes sure there is a remotes/origin/master or whatever, spelling out `refs/remotes/` just to be generally paranoid—feel free to remove `refs/remotes/` from these)

```
ahead=$(git rev-list --count refs/remotes/$remote/$branch..$branch)
if [ $ahead -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "$branch is ahead of $remote/$branch by $ahead commit(s)" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

(this makes sure there are no commits on $branch locally that are not present in the upstream)

```
. $(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup # for require_clean_work_tree
require_clean_work_tree "update from remote"
```

(this is somewhat optional, it depends on how strict you want to be about requiring that the tree be clean, but the next bits assume "clean")

```
git fetch $remote +refs/heads/$branch:refs/remotes/$remote/$branch
```

(this updates $remote/$branch to match what's actually on the remote now, regardless of any `fetch =` lines stored in the repository)

```
git reset --hard refs/remotes/$remote/$branch
```

(this last step moves `$branch`, which we've confirmed we're on, to point to the same commit as the newly updated `$remote/$branch`, and also replaces the work-directory contents with those from the newly updated post-fetch branch).

If some of the above steps fail (the "exit 1" bits, which might need modification for your purposes) then you fall back to re-cloning.

---

If you're willing to let the local repository grow (with more branches), you can ditch much of the above and simply run `git fetch` with the appropriate refspec, and/or add that refspec to the `fetch =` lines associated with the remote.  (Add a `git clean -fdx` to remove any files that should not be present, and note that the `git reset --hard` step will remove<sup>1</sup> any *commits* that should not be present.)

In particular, what `git clone --single-branch` does is *modify the fetch line* for the given remote.  For instance:

```
git clone --single-branch -b foo git://...
```

clones the repo and checks out branch `foo` as usual, but instead of leaving the `.git/config` entries for `origin` reading:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

it replaces the `fetch` line so that you have instead:

```
    fetch = +refs/heads/foo:refs/remotes/origin/foo
```

This means future `git fetch` operations—remember that `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by either merge or rebase—limit themselves to bringing over objects needed to update your local `refs/remotes/origin/foo` reflecting `refs/heads/foo` (branch foo) on the remote, rather than those for `refs/remotes/origin/*` (reflecting all branches on the remote through the first `*`).

If you wish to now update with `+refs/heads/bar:refs/remotes/origin/bar` (as if you'd cloned that branch), you can simply add or replace that as a (or the) `fetch =` line under `[remote "origin"]`.

If branches share a lot of history, this will save a lot of data-transfer over re-cloning, though of course you'll wind up with both `foo` and `bar` objects in the local repository.  If branches share very little history, there's little cost to starting over (unless you ever switch *back* of course).

---

<sup>1</sup>Except for traces left in the branch's reflogs.

Comment: Does all of this still work if $branch happens to be a tag instead of a branch?

Comment: No, or at least, not without some modifications.  Tags live in the `refs/tags/` name-space, and `git fetch` copies them in a peculiar manner by default.